# React context isn't available from function inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

Hello I have a problem with React Context. I'm using React-DnD and I'm trying to get context in `feed` function but it's empty. In this function I'm getting context default value but outside that function I'm getting correct values and I don't know why.

```
const Dog = () => {
const needsCtx = useContext(NeedsContext);
const invCtx = useContext(InventoryContext);
console.log(invCtx);
const feed = () => {
    console.log(invCtx);

};
needsCtx.saveCurrentContextToDatabase();
const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(
    () => ({
        accept: "food",
        drop: () => feed(),
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        }),
    }),
    []
);
return (
    <div className={styles["wrapper-dog"]}>
        <img ref={drop} className={styles.dog} alt="dog" src={dog}></img>
    </div>
);
};
```

context:

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
export const InventoryContext = React.createContext({
    items: {},
    setItems: () => {},
});

const InventoryContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState({});
    return (
        <InventoryContext.Provider value={{ items: items, setItems: setItems }}>
            {props.children}
        </InventoryContext.Provider>
    );
};
export default InventoryContextProvider;
```

Comment: To clarify: On line 4, it is printing the proper context. But when line 6 (inside the `feed` function) is called from further down, it is not printing the proper context? Is it printing at all?

Comment: Inside `feed` function it is printing the default values from context

Comment: As it should? I don't see you making any alterations to the `invCtx` anywhere.

Comment: No. It has got a value from `React.createContext` function and not from provider (in provider I'm setting a state to value and this is what I want to get in `feed` function)

Comment: Can you add the code for the component that includes the Provider?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make suggestions here, and continue to edit this answer.

```
<InventoryContext.Provider value={{ items: items, setItems: setItems }}>
```

This line confuses me most. Mostly because, you're using state inside of the Provider, so why do you also need to declare `items` and `setItems` inside the context itself?

Since you're using the state inside the Provider, couldn't you remove the `items` and `setItems` inside the context itself, and then just pass as:

```
<InvetoryContext.Provider value={{ items, setItems }}>
```